# Twinkle Twinkle, Little Ninja

Tags: word

What's going on here?

> One day an eastern leader
>   Shaved his face very closely.
>   At first, he thought this look was stylish,
>   Then apparently changed his mind.
>   His confidence was certainly rattled,
>   Leading to the dismissal of his obligation
>   To an independent lender
>   Who loaned him money for a movie
>   With a sometimes-fair princess who screams.

The answer will be nine words.

Comment: I noticed that there are nine lines. Does the answer include one word that explains each line (and that also makes sense, of course)?

Comment: answer will be : ENTERHERE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*T*winkle, *T*winkle, little star,  How I wonder what you are!

> Are you a *T*ongue *T*wister from Sheikh to Sheik - the little ninja alter ego of Princess Zelda.

This gives a sequence of nine words:

> Sheik(h) - sleek - chic - sucks - shook - shirk - shark - Shrek - Sheik

Considered alternative after second line:

> Slick keeping s---k style, but couldn't fit the fourth line.

Comment: You win! For posterity: Rot13(Furvx [Fuvpx](https://www.schick.com/) Puvp Fubbx Funxra Fuvex Funex Fuerx Furvx)